# Beamer: when new subsection starts, TOC with current section and that subsection (only)

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I have a problem with beamer. I would like to activate the TOC with just the current section and subsection every time a new subsection starts (I can already handle the case of activating the current section with all subsections at the beginning of every section). Below a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title[Title]{Title}
\author[Author]{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date[21/10/1985]{21/10/1985}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents%
[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Sub 1.1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Sub 1.2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Sub 2.1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Sub 2.2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I tried to add the following piece of code, but it didn't work.

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection, currentsubsection, hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame}
}
```

Any feedback will be most welcome.

Comment: Should the other subsection of the current section be completely hidden or only shaded?

Comment: Shaded, as for the other (inactive) section and subsections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more fine control if you use `subsectionstyle=<style for current subsection>/<style for other subsections in current section>/<style for subsections from other sections>` instead of `currentsubsection` and similar options. The possible styles are `show`, `shaded` and `hide`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[ sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/shaded]
  \end{frame}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Sub 1.1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Sub 1.2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section 2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Sub 2.1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Sub 2.2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bla}
Bla
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, this is not exactly what I was looking for (but very close). Indeed, when the section (alone) starts, I would like to have a TOC with the section and *all* its subsections visible. Once we move to specific subsections, I would like to get exactly what you suggested.

Comment: @Kolmin ... but don't you already have this in your code? I didn't repeat your `\AtBeginSection[]{...}` code because this question is about showing the toc at the start of subsections.

Comment: Supersorry. I overlooked the fact that that piece of code doesn't have to go. Yep, now everything works like a charm. Thanks a lot, much appreciated!

Comment: Actually, I just realized there is a problem, that was not originally mentioned. I have an option that is not in the original MW where, when I activate the section, only *its* subsections are showed. Can we have an answer that implements also this?

Comment: @Kolmin `subsectionstyle=show/show/hide`

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: If you prefer I can open a new question.

Comment: yes, I need to see some code and exactly where you want to show what.

Comment: Perfect: just give me a second.

Comment: Actually, I realized it's not needed to open a new question. The piece of code is the one you can find in my oringal question regarding AtBeginSubsection (the last piece of code). That delivers what I described above in the comments, but not what your answer delivered (my original problem). However, we get empty intersection.